# Sending message to Play Controller from Child Actors

Tags: websocket, playframework, akka

I am not clear on how to pass a message to an actor which has a constructor taking actorRef as argument.

I am trying to implement a simple websocket server using Play Framework.

I am receiving the client request in Controller and I can able to pass the request to Parent Actor(which takes actorRef as constructor argument) which in turn passes the request to child actor.

Once the child actor processed the request, I am not able to send back the response to controller.

```
@Singleton
class RequestController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit system: ActorSystem, mat: Materializer) extends AbstractController(cc) {
    def ws = WebSocket.accept[String, String] {req =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef { out =>
      ParentActor.props(out)
    }
  }
}
=======
object ParentActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new ParentActor(out))
}

class ParentActor(out : ActorRef) extends Actor {
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("ab")
    override def receive: Receive = {
         case msg: String => 
            val childActor: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[ChildActor])
            childActor ! msg
         case msg: Response => out ! msg
    }
}
==================
case class Response(name:String, msg:String)
class ChildActor extends Actor{
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("cd")
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case msg : String => 
        // Below statement is not working. I tried with sender() instead of self
        // which is also not working
        val parentActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new ParentActor(self))) 
        parentActor ! Response("ABC",msg) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are creating a new actor with the line

```
val parentActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new ParentActor(self)))
```

If you are sure that the message always comes from the appropriate ParentActor, you do not need to create a new actor and should be able to send the message to it with

```
sender() ! Response("ABC", message)
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try your suggestion and reply back